# How to use unique validation for only specific record in database table in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to validate unique question for specific `book_id`
it means is should be unique **only** specific record.

```
table: questions

$title = this is question 1

$book_id = 12
```

**TRUE** = if `question` not posted for `$book_id = 16`, user can post same `question`.

**Display Error** = if `question` posted for `$book_id = 12`, user not able to post.

This is what I tried so far

```
"required|unique:questions,question,book_id".$book_id,
"required|unique:questions,question,book_id,!".$book_id,
"required|unique:questions,question,NULL,id,book_id,".!$book_id,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make some custom validation like below

```
    class CustomValidator extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator {
      public function ValidatecheckQuestion($attribute, $value, $parameters) {

        $cnt = DB::table('questions')->where('title','=',$parameters[0])
                        ->where('book_id','=',12)
                        ->count();
        if($cnt==0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;                        
     }
  }
```

refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules to learn how to use custom validation exactly

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
"required|unique:questions,question,NULL,id,book_id,".$book_id,
```

Answer (score -1):

You would want to compare the title against the other title in your `questions` table in your database as below during creation:

```
'title' => 'unique:questions,title'
```